# Performance Issue when Updating Table from Another Table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to update old customers data with new data, so basically I'm updating firstname and lastname of old_customer_source table with firstname and lastname of new_customer_source table.

I indexed custid of new_customer_source but I don't have privileges to index old_customer_source's custid.

Total records to updated is ~50k and they query is taking over 30 mins to run!

Do you have any suggestions on how to improve the given Oracle query below?

```
update old_customer_source t1
   set   (t1.firstname, t1.lastname) = 
   (
    select  t2.firstname, t2.lastname
    from    new_customer_source t2
    where   t1.custid = t2.custid
   )
   where exists ( select 'x'
                from  new_customer_source t3
                where  t1.custid = t3.custid
              )
```

Comment: Nobody can tune a query by looking at it. Post the `execution plan`. And always mention the `database version` upto four decimals.

Comment: How big is `old_customer_source`?  Is it safe to assume that `new_customer_source` has ~50,000 rows since that's the number of rows updated?  Are there triggers on `old_customer_source` or unindexed foreign keys?

Comment: Both sources have 50,000 records. No, old_customer_source doesn't have FKs. No old_customer_source doesn't have triggers

Comment: @LalitKumarB, actually that is not true, there are many known performance problems in specific structures of SQL code such as, in this case, using a correlated subquery. If you have read anything about performance tuning for your database backend (and no one should ever query a databsse who has not read a performaince tuning book), then you will know the structures to avoid.

Comment: @HLGEM, in theory, theory and practice are same, in practice, they are different. So, it is good to see the execution plan, and make a practical decision. And it doesn't require to execute the query. With stats gathered, the execution plan could be 99% accurate. So, I asked for execution plan, because that's what I read in the performance tuning books. Oh by the way, regarding SQL tuning, ***It's all about cardinalities*** And you cannot know it just by looking at the SQL.

Comment: @LalitKumarB, for fine tuning performance yes. But I can look at a cursor and know if I replace it with a set-based query there is 99+% chance it will be faster. The same with a correlated subquery. or a  nonsargable where conditions. Or using Union to replace or conditions in a join. There are things where the performance is easily predicted and others where it depends on the situation. I am not saying to never use them, but most of the problems here are easily fixed by changing how the code is written (or adding the correct indexes) because they are not dependant on the database design.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. Performance tuning is a wide topic and a manual task to a great extent, and only the final testing could prove it. Thanks for your time to discuss.

Comment: use merge query [link](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/9i/merge-statement.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use merge.

```
merge into old_customer_source t1
using (select t2.custid, t2.firstname, t2.lastname
         from  new_customer_source t2
      ) t2
 on (t1.custid = t2.custid)
when matched then
update set t1.firstname = t2.firstname, 
           t1.lastname = t2.lastname
;
```