# How to update specific rows based on identified rows

Tags: sql, oracle

have identified specific rows based on unique id in the data. I want to update those rows one column. Trying to use update command but its not working

```
UPDATE L03_A_AVOX_DATA
   SET PWC_Exclusion_Flag =
          (CASE 
             WHEN (L03_A_AVOX_DATA.PWC_SEQ_AVOX IN
                      (SELECT  PWC_SEQ_AVOX
                         FROM L03_A_AVOX_DATA
                        WHERE     client_id IN
                                     (SELECT DISTINCT client_id
                                        FROM (  SELECT DISTINCT
                                                       client_id,
                                                       extract_type,
                                                       COUNT (*)
                                                  FROM temp
                                              GROUP BY client_id,
                                                       extract_type
                                                HAVING COUNT (*) = 1))
                              AND extract_type = '0'))
             THEN
                1
             ELSE
                L03_A_AVOX_DATA.PWC_Exclusion_Flag
          END )
```

Can anyone help me

Comment: Try to look at this my answer: [enter link description here][1]

It was similar question.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26042745/2235483

Answer (score 1):

You should simplify this statement by trying to simulate an UPDATE with JOIN.

For more details see here:

[Update statement with inner join on Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446764/oracle-update-statement-with-inner-join)

This idea should work for your case too.

So those records which have counterparts in the `temp` table, you update them.
Those which don't have counterparts - seems you don't want to update them anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to update the PWC_Exclusion_Flag to 1 if the client_id has exactly 1 record of extract_type 0 in the temp table, am I right?

Try this:

```
update L03_A_AVOX_DATA
set PWC_Exclusion_Flag = 1
where client_id in (
  select client_id
  from temp
  where extract_type = '0'
  group by client_id
  having count(1) = 1
);
```

This also leaves the other records in L03_A_AVOX_DATA untouched.